# Send email msg after form submitted?

Tags: php, forms

I have a mail script with a post form which gets sent to a mysql DB. Is there a way i can send a copy of the form data to an email or even just an alert type message like 'form has been submitted' I have tried adding another mail header but it doesn't seem to work.

PHP,

```
  <?php
    include('include/function.php');
    if (isset($_POST['Add'])){
    $client_id=addslashes( htmlspecialchars($_POST['client_id']));
    $proj_year=$_POST['year'];
    $feedback=addslashes( htmlspecialchars($_POST['feedback']));
    $proj_desc=addslashes( htmlspecialchars($_POST['proj_desc']));
    $rating=$_POST['rating'];
    $companyname=addslashes( htmlspecialchars($_POST['companyname']));
    if($_FILES['photo']['name']) {


    $photofile = $base_dir . date(His).basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $photofile)) {
    $photoname=date(His).$_FILES['photo']['name'];
    }
    }


    $sql="INSERT INTO review VALUES('','$client_id','$rating','$proj_desc','$companyname','$feedback',0)";

    if($client_id && $rating && $proj_desc && $feedback)
    $rset=mysql_query($sql);

    if($rset && mysql_affected_rows()>0)
    {

    $to      =$useremail;
    $subject = 'New Testimonial Added';
    $message = "Testimonial Details". "\r\n" ;
    $message.='Client Name :'.stripslashes($client_id). "\r\n" ;
    $message.='Testimonial :' .stripslashes($feedback). "\r\n" ;
    $headers = 'From:' .$to . "\r\n" ;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $successmsg="Testimonial has been added Successfully.";
    }
    else if(mysql_errno()==1062)
    {
    $errmsg="Duplicate data.";
    }
    else
    {
    $errmsg="Adding Testimonial failed.";
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Form type,

```
 <form name="addform" action="testimonial.php" id="myform"              enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:return validatefrm();>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The to argument in phps mail function accepts multiple emails separated by a comma:

```
mail($to . ',your@email.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php